Itext 7.0 - Acroforms are empty
I have a PDF form with filled out fields. If I try to read the acrofields they are empty. But in the PDF I can change the values and save them.
namespace Tutorial {
    public class FillForm {
        public const String SRC = "../../../resources/pdf/dnd-character.pdf";
        public const String DEST = "../../../results/fill_dnd.pdf";

        public static void Main(String[] args) {
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(DEST);
            file.Directory.Create();
            new FillForm().ManipulatePdf(SRC, DEST);
        }

        public virtual void ManipulatePdf(String src, String dest) {
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
            PdfAcroForm form = PdfFormCreator.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);
            IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetAllFormFields();
            Console.WriteLine(fields.Count);
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, PdfFormField> entry in fields)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(entry.Key);
            }
            pdf.Close();
        }
    }
}

Here is the pdf: PDF
My code works with other PDFs, so I feel confident its a PDF issue. Here is a PDF it works with: PDF2
I tried looking into this myself, but the best I could find is this outdated stack question here: ItextSharp - Acrofields are empty
This solution uses the following line:
PdfArray fields = form.GetAsArray(PdfName.Fields);

which returns the error: Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
I then looked at this question: iText Acrofields Are Empty, form.getAsArray(PdfName.FIELDS) is also null

Again, this solution uses form.GetAsArray(PdfName.Fields);  so this solution fails for me too. I also checked for Xfa like in the question and that does not seem to present
XfaForm xfa = form.GetXfaForm();
xfa.IsXfaPresent()  // returns false

However, this question led me to look at the PDF Hierarchy in RUPS, and I noticed a difference. Here is the hierarchy of the PDF that works:

The highlighted /T is the reference I want to use to get the string inside /V
Here is the hierarchy of the pdf that doesn't work:

Again, Want /V using /T (or any other way to specifically get /V really). So, how do I work with this seemingly bad pdf to get the information I want?

It looks like the second file doesn't have an AcroForm entry in the Catalog. Thus, it doesn't have an AcroForm form.

@mkl Makes sense. What are the fillable spaces on the pdf then? How might I get them in itext?

@KJ I dont know what most of that means but Ill start looking that up I. Any hints on where to start?

@KJ This is great! This conversion works! I can use the DND form with my itext script. What did you do to it to change it? I know very very little about working with pdf back end, im just diving into this for this one side project.

@KJ I think the opposite because the job app form works with my code but the DND form does not. That + some other questions framing pdfs that dont work with my code as "badly structured" pdfs led me to refer to them this way. I dont really care which one is formatted better, I just want to get the information I need using itext.

@Jesse "Makes sense. What are the fillable spaces on the pdf then? How might I get them in itext?" - Well, those are AcroForm field Widgets, but the central AcroForm form element is missing. PDF viewers automatically visit the PDF pages and their annotations to display them, so they find the widgets there and allow the user to fill them in, but for plain PDF libraries there is no need to inspect the pages, so they usually inspect AcroForm forms starting from the central form element.

As you yourself pointed out in the question itself, the problem here comes from the fact, that this "broken" PDF file contains widget annotations, but doesn't contain AcroForm entry in the catalog. This entry serves as an entry point for basically everything related to form fields and widgets, and since it is missing, iText is not able to retrieve desired information in it's usual way.
However it is still possible to get this information. In order to do so, one needs to iterate through all the pages in the document and collect all the widgets.
Something like this should do the trick:
using (PdfDocument pdfDocument1 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("DnD-Character.pdf")))
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < pdfDocument1.GetNumberOfPages() + 1; ++i)
                {
                    PdfPage page = pdfDocument1.GetPage(i);
                    foreach (PdfAnnotation annotation in page.GetAnnotations())
                    {
                        if (PdfName.Widget.Equals(annotation.GetSubtype()))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + annotation.GetPdfObject().Get(PdfName.T));
                            Console.WriteLine("Value: " + annotation.GetPdfObject().Get(PdfName.V));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

